# Is there any guide how to handle the uncaught exception in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception

Originally, `uncaughtException` is used in my code to catch all unhandled exceptions.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  if ('stack' in err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
  }
});
```

However it is not a good way, according to this [post](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception), we know

```
`uncaughtException` is a very crude mechanism for exception handling and 
may be removed in the future.
And use `domains` instead. If you do use it, restart your application 
after every unhandled exception!
Do not use it as the node.js equivalent of On Error Resume Next.
```

Also the module [`forever`](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) is another good way to do that.

Here are my questions:

- What does `On Error Resume Next` mean?
- Is there any guide how to handle the uncaught exception in nodejs?

Comment: `on error resume next` was an option in Visual Basic 6 (probably others too, but that's where I know it from) that would ignore all errors in a section of code, and continue execution uninterrupted. This made it difficult to debug because you wouldn't get a specific message that an error occurred, you'd just get a nonsense result.

Comment: So, why are you not using "Domain"?

Comment: @pmverma, currently not. I will try it, but I want to know should I combine it with `forever`?

Comment: @zangw, I am not sure about your project's type,size,scope..so so, I can not tell should or should not. But in my previous project, At first I used forever to run my project. But through time, I realize that I do not have full control to my project such as handling SIGNAL in my process, can not write log to file when the process is about to exit,etc.So I removed forever module, and write a simple custom code and use domain and running fine.

Comment: @pmverma, could you please give me some clue about your custom code?

Comment: Domains are very likely to be deprecated soon.

Comment: @minitech Then which one we should for handling error?

Comment: @minitech why `domain` will be deprecated?

Comment: @pmverma: I like [promises](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bluebird), myself. zangw: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/reTInaFyC2s

Answer (score 1):

`On Error Resume Next` is a Visual Basic (and VB.NET!) construct that causes any exception that reaches its scope to be ignored and execution to be continued. (That’s a bad idea, to be clear.) It looks like this:

```vb
Sub Example()
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim x As String = Nothing
    Dim y As String = x.Substring(0, 5) ' Fails! Ignored! y is Nothing, probably

    Console.WriteLine(y) ' Execution continues
End Sub
```

It’s kind of like starting every statement with `@` in PHP, as another example.

`forever` is the correct way to restart a script that shouldn’t terminate when an unhandled exception occurs.

Comment: It's still in VB.NET? Wow. I'd have thought that was the kind of thing they'd kill when they had the chance.

Comment: @JeremyBanks: Not only `Resume Next`, but also `GoTo label|0|-1`! I actually have used one of those before, for a good reason. But only once. =)

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [this](http://shapeshed.com/uncaught-exceptions-in-node/)

- You application shouldn't have uncaught exceptions. This is clearly insane.
- You should let your application crash, find uncaught exceptions and fix them. This is clearly insane.
- You should swallow errors silently. This is what lots of people do and it is bad.
- You should let your application crash, log errors and restart your process with something like upstart, forever or monit. This is pragmatic.
- You should start using domains to handle errors. Clearly the way to go, although this is an experimental feature of Node.

Comment: The same link which i used